# How to run Spark application assembled with Spark 1.6 on cluster with Spark 2.0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, sbt-assembly

I'm trying to execute an application that is assembled with Spark 1.6 in a EMR cluster that has Spark 2.0 installed.

Is that possible?

Comment: You cannot run a Spark application built using v1.6 on a Spark Cluster created using v2.0.

Comment: As pointed out by @himanshuIIITian , you can't do that.